# How to read data from ESP32 via Bluetooth in Android Studio

Tags: java

I have tried to read data from ESP32 via Bluetooth in Android Studio. But what I could get so far is write(send) the content of data from app to ESP32. How Can I read data and show in app?
Because when I run the code below and call the function "receber"(mmInStream) through a button, the app freezes.

```java
public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    mmSocket = socket;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;
    try {
         tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
    }
    try {
         tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
    }
         mmInStream = tmpIn;
         mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

public void enviar(String dadosEnviar) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = dadosEnviar.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);


              
            } catch (IOException e) {

               
            }
        }

        public String receber(String dadosLidos) {

            byte[] msgBuffer = dadosLidos.getBytes();
            try {

                int bytes = mmInStream.read(msgBuffer);
                String readMessage = new String(msgBuffer, 0, bytes);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, readMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                
            } catch (IOException e) {

                


            }
            return dadosLidos;
```